# Postgres Upsert Cardinality Violation

Tags: postgresql, upsert

I am trying to insert extracted data from a sql table into a postgres table where the rows may or may not exist. If they do exist, I would like to set a specific column to its default (0)

The table is as

```
site_notes (
job_id text primary key,
attachment_id text,
complete int default 0);
```

My query is

```
INSERT INTO site_notes (
                job_id,
                attachment_id
            )
            VALUES 
                {jobs_sql}
            ON CONFLICT (job_id) DO UPDATE
            SET complete = DEFAULT;
```

However I am getting an error: *psycopg2.errors.CardinalityViolation: ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE command cannot affect row a second time
HINT:  Ensure that no rows proposed for insertion within the same command have duplicate constrained values.*

Would anyone be able to advise on how to set the *complete* column to the default on event of a conflict ?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` statement (and indeed an `UPDATE` statement too) is not allowed to modify the same row more than once. It is not clear what `{jobs_sql}` in your question is, but it must contain several rows, and at least two of those have the same `job_id`.

Make sure that the same `job_id` does not occur more than once in the rows you want to `INSERT`.